# log4net MVC aspnetrequest values missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net

The value for `aspnetrequest` in the log is outputting server variables without values. How can I get it to log the values in addition to the names?

```
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@aspnetrequest" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="1024" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%aspnet-request" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

This is what I get in the log:

`{ASP.NET_SessionId, ALL_HTTP, ALL_RAW, APPL_MD_PATH, APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH, AUTH_TYPE, AUTH_USER, AUTH_PASSWORD, LOGON_USER, REMOTE_USER, CERT_COOKIE, CERT_FLAGS, CERT_ISSUER, CERT_KEYSIZE, CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE, CERT_SERIALNUMBER, CERT_SERVER_ISSUER, CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT, CERT_SUBJECT, CONTENT_LENGTH, CONTENT_TYPE, GATEWAY_INTERFACE, HTTPS, HTTPS_KEYSIZE, HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE, HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER, HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT, INSTANCE_ID, INSTANCE_META_PATH, LOCAL_ADDR, PATH_INFO, PATH_TRANSLATED, QUERY_STRING, REMOTE_ADDR, REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT, REQUEST_METHOD, SCRIPT_NAME, SERVER_NAME, SERVER_PORT, SERVER_PORT_SECURE, SERVER_PROTOCOL, SERVER_SOFTWARE, URL, HTTP_CONNECTION, HTTP_ACCEPT, HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING, HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, HTTP_COOKIE, HTTP_HOST, HTTP_USER_AGENT}`

Comment: It seems you are using buffered appender. Can you set the buffer size to 0? It could be the session is not longer available at the moment the actual message is written.

Comment: @Peter tried that - no luck